# xamarin droid project doesn't build after move to x64 java jdk

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an xamarin android project. It worked and built so far. Now I changed the jdk1.8 from the x86 to the x64 since the Xamarin Forms designer needs this version to work properly according to Xamarin. Now I get this error on build:

```
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1965,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2.
```

I read that this might be related to newer support libraries of google. But i have the newest version and had it already before I made the change. I also tried reboot my pc, clean and rebuild and delete all bin and obj folders without success. And so far I haven't found more information what this error could be and how to solve it besides switch back to the x86 version of the jdk.

Comment: Please include a full diagnostic build error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, while getting the diagnostic build log. I added the xamarin forms nuget package for embedded forms. With that package, the references exceed the max of what android is able to handle. So I had to enable multi-dex first. Then it built again.

Comment: Yes, as a further explanation. Dalvik has a compile-time limit of 65k method signatures, by adding large packages like Google Play Service you can easily exceed this limit. Multi-dex solves this by splitting your code into multiple files, much like `.dll`s, called upon as needed at run-time.